# Google Voice Recognition Android onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, voice

In my google voice recognition, I'm trying to add commands. The commands should be in this piece of code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // add commands 
    }
}
```

I am guessing it would be a else if statement but I'm confused on how to start it.

```
if() {
    // put code here
}
```

But what should I put in the `if` and the `put code here`?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the requestCode and resultCode like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SystemData.VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        // TODO something with matches
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The 'matches' ArrayList will contain all the recognized words in order.

Comment: So should i create an array called 'matches' with the keywords in it?  Where should i put this array.  Then after i have the array, how should i do the code in the onActivityResult?

Comment: The arraylist called matches will get "created" for you, all you need to do is iterate through it and apply some logic on each item (where the TODO is).